# Do I get to take a unique squadmate power for my character?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 2, you could unlock certain powers with your squad mates, which you could then choose one of to take and use yourself.  For example, I was very partial to Mordin's Neural Shock ability.

Does Mass Effect 3 allow you to unlock powers again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. And, unlike in Mass Effect 2, these powers are unlocked very soon after earning the squadmates to begin with.

It's unclear as of yet if *every* loyalty power survived between the two games, but the concept still exists, as do the specialty power of individual squadmates (i.e., Armor Piercing Ammo for Garrus).

Comment: [Here is a full list of squadmates and their powers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53828/13314)