# What specific Bonus/Loyalty powers are available?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I know that the concept of [Bonus Powers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53604/do-i-get-to-take-a-unique-squadmate-power-for-my-character) earned from loyal squadmates to enhance Shepards abilities has been retained. But what I can't find any information on is *what specific powers* are availiable.

I'm trying to plan out my build for my Vanguard at the moment, and I'd really like to know if certain abilities, such as Carnage or Reave will be available to me, so that I can figure out which powers I'll select to eventually complement it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Confirmed

> **Garrus** - Armor Piercing Ammo
>
> **Garrus** - Proximity Mine(unlocked 2nd)
>
> **Liara** - Warp Ammo (Note: This is different than Liara's bonus power in ME2)
>
> **Liara** - Stasis
>
> **James** - Fortification
>
> **James** - Carnage (unlocked 2nd)
>
> **EDI** - Defensive Matrix
>
> **EDI** -  Decoy
>
> **Ashley** - Inferno Grenade
>
> **Ashley** - Marksman (unlocked 2nd)
>
> **Kaidan** - Barrier
>
> **Kaidan** - Reave (unlocked 2nd)
>
> **Tali** - Energy Drain
>
> **Tali** - Defense Drone (unlocked 2nd)
>
> **Javik** (*From Ashes* DLC) - Slam
>
> **Javik** (*From Ashes* DLC) - Dark Charge

It appears that *every* squadmate has 4 active powers. Two of them are availiable to one of the six character classes as a baseline skill. The other two will become availiable to any class as a bonus power.

Comment: Feel free to move those from unconfirmed to confirmed as you go Raven, but I'm pretty damned sure that's the list.

Comment: I can confirm EDI's Decoy power. It just unlocked for me after a conversation with her about "modifying her self-preservation code".