# How do I unlock bonus powers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

There [seems to be a variety of bonus powers available in Mass Effect 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53802/what-specific-bonus-loyalty-powers-are-available), I'm wondering what I have to do to unlock all of those.

What are the exact requirements on unlocking those bonus powers? Do they only come into play when I start a new game, or can I use them in the same game when I unlock them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can learn a single power in the Normandy Medical bay. Learning a new one will replace the old power. It costs 5000 credits.

Powers will be unlocked through dialogue with your companions. Each has 2 powers to give, one generally unlocking fairly early and the other one significantly later. Make sure to talk to them after a mission both on the Normandy and in the various Citadel districts.

Comment: Do you get the points invested in those if you replace them?

Comment: If you have points assigned to a bonus power and pick a different power, those points will be unassigned automatically, so you'll need to manually assign them to the bonus power again.